# manually create categorical variable instead of fitting an interaction term

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, interaction, stata

I am running a logistic regression model and I want to fit an interaction term between a dummy (female) and a categorical variable (risk level; 0/1/2). I was wondering whether creating my variable rather than fitting an interaction term gives me the same results. I have created my variable as follows:

Combination = 0 if female==0 & risk_level==0
combination = 1 if female==1 & risk_level==0
Combination = 2 if female==0 & risk_level==1
combination = 3 if female==1 & risk_level==1
Combination = 4 if female==0 & risk_level==2
combination = 5 if female==1 & risk_level==2

Therefore, my Stata code for the two logistic regressions would be

logistic outcome i.female##i.risk_level age i.income_quintile

and

logistic outcome i.combination age i.income_quintile

I decided to create it manually as I do not want to fit lincom or margins after but double-checking if this is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: Note that the two regressions might choose different base levels for the dummies, which could lead to different coefficients for otherwise equivalent models.